# Distinct count SSAS

Tags: count, ssas, distinct

I’m facing a little issue to calculate a distinct count a number of clients in SSAS OLAP Cube. The difficulty appears for the credited client’s accounts, in other words, for the clients how have credit (quantity = -1) or for the clients how have bought the product and they receive a credit after (quantity = 0). My actual distinct count in my cube considers these two cases as real buying transaction, but in fact they’re not.  I’ve checked in SSAS to make a distinct count with the expression (SUM Quantity > 1), but I didn’t find nothing. Now I’m thinking to model these cases directly in my Datawarehouse, but I don’t see how can’t do it.  Can anyone de give me a little help? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would feed this data into SSAS using a SQL View.  Within that View I would define a calculation to return NULL for the rows you dont want to count, something like this:

`CASE WHEN quantity <= 0 THEN NULL ELSE Client_Account END AS Client_Account_For_Distinct_Count`

Then I would use that column as the basis of the SSAS Distinct Count measure.